# Cannot change status bar text color on large screen iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, statusbar

I'm working on an old Object C app using `tabBarController`. Because `setStatusBarStyle` that was used to set status bar text to white is deprecated in iOS 9 so I deleted it and changed the .plist file like:
[image]

I also changed Status Bar Style in Deployment Info to 'Light'.
It worked fine with iPhone SE and 5 (checked with iOS 9.3 and 11) but for some reason didn't work with larger devices such as iPhone 6 or 7. Status bar and its content (time, battery etc.) are both black.
I tried `preferredStatusBarStyle` as suggested and some other instructions but nothing worked perfectly for me.

Comment: Whats your project deployment target?

Comment: If your deployment target is > 9 then use - (UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle
{
    return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
}
use this in every view controller class(.m file).

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is here:

This code use every **UIViewController**

```
- (UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle
{
    return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
```

use `- (void)viewDidLoad` 
or 
`- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated`